# All scheduled sidekiq jobs are not excuting in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, scheduled-tasks, sidekiq

I have scheduled 50 sidekiq cron jobs yesterday.
All jobs were showing under the sidekiq/cron tab. However, some of jobs are not executed.
I have checked the log file and there is no error.

I have set the following code in Worker files.

```
Sidekiq::Cron::Job.create(name: "MultiSingle Post, Store Name: #{store_rotation[:name]}, Date: #{t_hours}-#{minutes},#{date_arr[0]}/#{date_arr[1]}, Number:#{i}", cron: "#{minutes} #{t_hours} #{date_arr[0]} #{date_arr[1]} * Asia/Karachi", class: 'MultiSinglePostWorker', args:data)

include Sidekiq::Worker
sidekiq_options :retry => 0
```

Still, all scheduled jobs are showing in the corn tab(executed + not executed).

How I can execute all scheduled jobs?

Comment: Have you started the sidekiq process?

Comment: Yes. sidekiq process was enabled.